# Is there some way to "fully delete" received and sent SMS messages (and any other "deleted" data") on my cellphone?

Tags: phone, deletion, sms

I have a cheap cellphone bought about ten years ago. It has a physical SIM card. I have in-phone "deleted" all sent and received messages, but very strongly suspect that these are still there (as well as any deleted contacts) whether I stored them on the SIM card or on the internal storage memory of the phone.

I bet anyone with special knowledge stealing my phone could retrieve the messages. Or cops. (Obviously, in the latter case, they also can retrieve it from the phone provider or whatever database stores all messages sent on a network level, but that's a bit different and nothing I can do anything about.)

I'd like to know if there is some sort of "secret poweruser mode" I can enter with some sort of code which then lets me fully "nuke" the deleted data from at least the SIM card and the internal phone memory, just like the `CIPHER` command in Windows allegedly allows you to "fully delete" deleted files on your internal disks or any storage device (such as a USB memstick or flash card) by writing those areas over with zeroes, ones and random zeroes/ones.

Comment: It would *obviously* be dependent on the phone model and what software it uses. The answer ranges from possibly to no.

Comment: @vidarlo "Samsung GT-E1200R", but I was hoping for an universal answer.